# Custom C preprocessor format in Emacs cc-mode

Tags: emacs, indentation, mako, font-lock, cc-mode

I'm generating a C source file from a [Mako](https://www.makotemplates.org/) template. Mako templates have directives similar to C preprocessor directives, except that they start with `%` instead of `#`. For example:

```c
%if some_condition:
   /* Condition is true */
%else:
   /* Condition is false */
%endif
```

When editing the template source, those directives play havoc with `cc-mode`'s font locking and automatic indentation.

Is there a way to tell `cc-mode` that it should handle lines that start with a `%` in the same way as preprocessor lines (that start with a `#`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a simpler way, but since cc-mode prepares the fontification stuff at compile time, I'm not sure how you would get the fontification without declaring a derived cc-mode (without simply adding them all via `font-lock-add-keywords`).

The indentation could be modified alone by just setting the `c-opt-*` variables below in your `c-mode-hook`, I believe, and not bothering with the rest.  But, here is an example derived mode that will fontify your preprocessor statements and provide the proper indentation (hopefully), after calling `mako-mode` from your buffer.

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cc-langs)
  (require 'cc-fonts))
(require 'cc-mode)

;;; create inherited mako-mode from c-mode
(eval-and-compile (c-add-language 'mako-mode 'c-mode))

;;; variables to control font-locking preprocessor stuff
(c-lang-defconst c-cpp-expr-intro-re mako
                 (concat "\\s *%\\s*" (regexp-opt '("if" "else" "endif")) ":?"))
(c-lang-defconst c-opt-cpp-prefix mako "\\s *%")
(c-lang-defconst c-opt-cpp-symbol mako "%")
(c-lang-defconst c-opt-cpp-start mako "\\s *%\\s *\\([[:alnum:]:]+\\)")

(defconst mako-font-lock-keywords-1 (c-lang-const c-matchers-1 mako))
(defconst mako-font-lock-keywords-2 (c-lang-const c-matchers-2 mako))
(defconst mako-font-lock-keywords-3 (c-lang-const c-matchers-3 mako))
(defvar mako-font-lock-keywords (c-lang-const c-matchers-3 mako))
(defun mako-font-lock-keywords ()
  (c-compose-keywords-list mako-font-lock-keywords))

(defvar mako-mode-syntax-table nil)
(define-derived-mode mako-mode prog-mode "Mako"
  :after-hook (c-update-modeline)
  :syntax-table c-mode-syntax-table

  ;; initialize cc-mode stuff
  (c-initialize-cc-mode t)
  (c-init-language-vars mako-mode)
  (c-common-init 'mako-mode))
```